# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 (CCControlButton)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, armv7, undefined-symbol

I am using CBReader to read cocoabuilder file. on simulator is working fine. but when i am trying to run od my iPad, its giving me compilation error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_CCControl.state_", referenced from:
      -[CCControlButton setTitle:forState:] in CCControlButton.o
      -[CCControlButton setTitleColor:forState:] in CCControlButton.o
      -[CCControlButton setTitleLabel:forState:] in CCControlButton.o
      -[CCControlButton setBackgroundSprite:forState:] in CCControlButton.o
      -[CCControlButton needsLayout] in CCControlButton.o
      -[CCControlButton ccTouchBegan:withEvent:] in CCControlButton.o
      -[CCControlButton ccTouchMoved:withEvent:] in CCControlButton.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_CCControl.highlighted_", referenced from:
      -[CCControlButton setHighlighted:] in CCControlButton.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help!

Comment: Similar issue happened to me [Static library gives error on iOS simulator and works on iOS device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356837/static-library-gives-error-on-ios-simulator-and-works-on-ios-device)

Comment: I have problem with device. its working on iOS Simulator nicely. not on device. i am using CCBReader, this is not build as framework, this are simply bunch of classes.

Comment: Have you added `CCControlButton.m` file to the target compiled sources you are building?

Comment: check that armv7 is listed under architectures in build settings, also try setting build only active target to no