# Create static library Xcode 4.6

Tags: static-libraries, xcode4.6

I'm building static library in Xcode 4.6. http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/. I building follow post but wrong error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSHelloer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

---

## Solved

I found reason to error. *I'm playing app in simulator, static libs build for device.* So wrong error.

Comment: http://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Undefined+symbols+for+architecture+i386:+%22_OBJC_CLASS_%24&oq=Undefined+symbols+for+architecture+i386:+%22_OBJC_CLASS_%24&gs_l=hp.3..0l2.419.419.0.2271.1.1.0.0.0.0.90.90.1.1.0...0.0...1c.2.15.psy-ab.5IaYMWuNeUk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.dmQ&fp=40737dd545adc298&biw=1132&bih=1068

Comment: you can compile your .a file to use for both simulator and device: ihttp://stackoverflow.com/a/2996304