# SDWebImage Framework Not Found iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I am using `SDWebImage` in my app and it was working quiet fine. I just updated the SDK and now I am having issues in it.

I have added the framework for all targets in my project. Still I get this error when I try to build my project.

[image]

I have googled it but none of the solutions were referring to my issue.

Comment: did you find a solution for it?

Comment: Its not a solution in fact but, a work around.

Comment: I realized that my problem was having multiple target with different platforms declared in Podfile.. Cocoapods seems to have problems with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices to fix this.

- Use static library `.a` file. For this you will have to make fat library using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2996304/3081929).
- User files rather than using the framework. You can find these files in SDWebImage-master -> SDWebImage directory.

[image]

I personally prefer second option.

I hope this will help.