# Mac : symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode9.2, xcode-workspace

I'm trying to build a mac application which is going to use one static library.
I created one workspace and added my application project and static library project to workspace and added linked application framework or libraries to my result library.

I'm able to compile my library project individually and able to get .a file out of it. But when i run the application, I'm getting linker error saying **symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64**

- I verified valid architectures in app and static lib projects. both having i386, x86_64

Can any one help me on this.

Thanks for understanding the problem.

Comment: Could you please check out this link. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996235/how-to-build-a-library-for-both-iphone-simulator-and-device/2996304#2996304

Comment: **symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64** 
This is only part of the error message; the rest of the message will tell you the name of the function that has been declared, but whose implementation is not found.