# Jenkins iOS build for both simulator and device

Tags: ios, jenkins, build

Let me start by saying I know how to create fat library manually, as described in this post: [How to build a library for both iPhone simulator and device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996235/how-to-build-a-library-for-both-iphone-simulator-and-device)

My question is, does anyone know how to configure Jenkins to do the same job?

A little background: I am creating a library, thus every time I'm doing release, I have to go through all the process of building for simulator and device, then go into their respective folders to grab the frameworks produced, and lump them together using the lipo tool.

I'm able to automate the lumping process through a script, so I'm wondering if I can automate Jenkins to output frameworks for both architecture types and call then call this custom script.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build them one by one. Follow, combine them by lipo.

```
CURRENTPATH=`pwd`

xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -configuration 
  ${CONFIGURATION} - 
  sdk iphoneos clean build ARCHS='armv7 armv7s' 
  IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='5.0' 
  TARGET_BUILD_DIR='./build-arm' BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR='./build-arm'

 xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} 
  -sdk iphoneos clean build ARCHS='arm64' IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='7.0' 
   TARGET_BUILD_DIR='./build-arm64' BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR='./build-arm64'

xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} - 
  sdk iphonesimulator clean build ARCHS='i386' IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='5.0' 
  TARGET_BUILD_DIR='./build-i386' BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR='./build-i386'

xcodebuild -project ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} - 
  sdk iphonesimulator clean build ARCHS='x86_64' VALID_ARCHS='x86_64' 
  IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='7.0' TARGET_BUILD_DIR='./build-x86_64' 
  BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR='./build-x86_64'

cp -r "${CURRENTPATH}/build-arm64/include" "${CURRENTPATH}/build-universal"

lipo -create ./build-arm/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a ./build- 
  arm64/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a ./build-i386/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a ./build- 
   x86_64/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a -output ./build-universal/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a
```

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: taken as accepted solution as it's the path I turn out to follow